# The was automatically turned on and we can't turn the fan off

Tags: electrical, heating, ceiling-fan, gas

The indoor central gas heating system was automatically turned on even though we did not touch anything. The room temperature was not colder than other days. Then this is the worse thing, we can't turn the fan off. Please let me know anything you need further.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Make/model of the furnace & thermostat would be a good start. Do you own or rent? Where in the world are you located? The more details you can provide, the better the answer will be that you get. Please [edit] them into your post, and don't provide them down here in the comments - comments get lost, or sometimes deleted.

Comment: Did you recently change out the thermostat??

Comment: To be more explicit, if you rent, contact your landlord!

Comment: Start by reading the owner's manual. If you don't have one, go to the internet and download one.   Almost certainly somone has moved some switch or setting from "Fan when called upon" to "Fan on always"

Answer (score 2):

There is usually a shutoff switch for the system located near it - sometimes there is also one located in a more convenient location.

If not, find the correct circuit breaker and shut that off.

Comment: This is a Microsoft answer: completely correct and completely useless.  If they kill power to the system, they get no A/C or heat.

Comment: They appear, based on the question, to want the system **off, right now.** Presumably they will deal with repair before they need heat (or cooling, if it even cools. Probably not, since it was described as "a central gas heating system.") *But do feel free to provide an answer you consider "better."*